# JPA ignores left outer join annotation when adding an ORDER BY clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, outer-join

I have an Entity which looks about this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOG_ENTRY")
public class LogEntry implements Serializable {

...
    @JoinFetch(JoinFetchType.OUTER)
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SERVER_ID")
    private Server server;
...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "SERVER")
public class Server extends implements Serializable {
...
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
...
}
```

when I construct a query in the following way:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<LogEntry> criteria = builder.createQuery(LogEntry.class);
Root<LogEntry> root = criteria.from(LogEntry.class);
```

The resault SQL is correct:

```
SELECT t0.NAME FROM {oj LOG_ENTRY t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN SERVER t0 ON (t0.ID = t1.SERVER_ID)}
```

But when I add the orderBy to the criteria in the following manner:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<LogEntry> criteria = builder.createQuery(LogEntry.class);
Root<LogEntry> root = criteria.from(LogEntry.class);
criteria.orderBy(builder.desc(root.get("server.name")));
```

I am getting the following SQL (without the outer join!!!)

```
SELECT t0.NAME FROM SERVER t0, LOG_ENTRY t1 WHERE (t0.ID = t1.SERVER_ID) ORDER BY t0.NAME DESC
```

I'm using eclipselink 2.3.3 (you might noticed that since I'm using the org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.JoinFetch in my Entity)

Is there any way to solve this? 
Will switching to Hibernate make it behave correctly?

Comment: Try `@ManyToOne(optional = true)`